# Wordpress Sidebar not showing up in BE on Testserver

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress Page (running in Mamp) with my own theme. I also have I Sidebar, which is showing up perfectly in CMS Backend and Frontend - Locally. I pushed my Page to a Testserver, and the Sidebar is not showing up in the Backend. There are no Widgets, even though the Widgets are in my Database.
I have no clue about that. Do you?

This is the code how I registered the Sidebar in functions.php

```
  register_sidebar(array(
  'name' => __('Primary Sidebar', 'mytheme'),
  'id' => 'primary-sidebar',
  'description' => __('Main sidebar.', 'mytheme'),
  'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="sidebar-box %2$s ">',
  'after_widget' => '</div>',
  'before_title' => '<h3>',
  'after_title' => '</h3>',
));
```

Comment: please on the define('WP_DEBUG', true); in wp-config.php, this will display the errors of your site.

Comment: I did that - there seems to be nothing wrong, there are no errors showing up (normally they do if there would be some)